# Search As You Type in C# Using DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, full-text-search, datasource

I just wanted to share some knowledge with everyone because I spent almost a half a day searching for a "Search as you type" solution using winforms in VS2017. Most of the other solutions I found used a SQL database as the datasource or recommended using other tools or controls which was not the solution I was looking for.

Anyways, I made a Request to a Web API and put the Response into a List. Then, I used that List as the DataGridView control's DataSource. Then I used the Key_Up as a trigger. Below is my final solution that works great!

Hope this helps!

Comment: To make your knowledge sharing effective and make your post useful for future readers in stackoverflow format, you should ask a good question and post a good answer to the question. It would be great if you read about [ASK] and [ANSWER].

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought this was good to share since I couldn't find a good answer myself.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not good to share. Your question has a good title, but lacks good description. In fact you are telling a story about the solution, while you should describe the problem which you are trying to solve, share some code, expected output, ... . By asking a good question you will help future readers know if they have the same problem. Also by asking a good question, you may receive some good answer or point to some duplicate links. Also about the answer, it should contain some description about the solution and how it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AddUser_API
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*Makes the request to API for the groups when the form loads. I obviously have a different class that handles this request*/
            Request userClient = new Request();

            //endpoint is a GET request
            userClient.endPoint = userClient.endPoint;
            userClient.httpMethod = httpVerb.GET;

            string strResponse = string.Empty;

            strResponse = userClient.makeRequest();

            /*This will put the response into a list then fill the datagridview control with the Web API response*/

            List<getUser> grpName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<getUser>>(strResponse);

            dgvUserList.DataSource = grpName;

//Cosmetics
                dgvUserList.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 28, 0);
                dgvUserList.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 28, 0);   
            }

/* the following key up will allow the user to search as they type in the textbox control*/

        private void txtbxByUsername_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            string searchValue = txtbxByUsername.Text.ToLower();
            dgvUserList.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvUserList.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[i].Value != null && row.Cells[i].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchValue))
                        {
                            int rowIndex = row.Index;
                            dgvUserList.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// This will color each cell in the column "_fieldName" if the textbox1.text is found.

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{

if(Row.Cells["_fieldName"].Value.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToUpper())) {Row.Cells["_invoice"].Style.BackColor = Color.Goldenrod;}

else { Row.Cells["_fieldName"].Style.BackColor = Color.White;}
}